# Changing background image one time on responsive background image

Tags: jquery, css, background, responsive-design

The code I'm using is this one

```
background: url(bilder/cover.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

What I'd like to accomplish is that the background image is changed after like 2 sec to a background image that then stays put.

I know there are Jqueries for changing backgrounds like this but I'm not sure how to make something like that work with the code I'm using! It would be awesome if someone hade a solution to this!

My starting point for changing background was the code I found on w3schools:

```
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
animation:myfirst 5s;
-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
from {background:red;}
to {background:yellow;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {background:red;}
to {background:yellow;}
}
```

Comment: what code do you have so far ? Cos the only answer i can give you now is *www.guru.com* = Hire a coder.

Comment: Lol @MilchePatern I was thinking the same thing, not to mention the link died on me. I was looking in the FAQ, can't find it now, but I know SO has a mention about not "just posting a link"

Comment: I've updated the question! sorry!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mistype "bilder"? Looks like that should be "builder"

Comment: @user2141649 Good thing you pasted the CSS, now, what technique have you tried ? What css-transition or javascript code have you tried ? By the way, look on the right side of this page under the **Related** items, you might find some verry relevant questions/topics to your situation.

Comment: I've added what I tried so far!

Comment: `"My starting point for changing background was the code I found on w3schools"` ... [Ouch!](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: well i'm a noob, can't you tell! I'm good with design but I'm trying to learn!

Comment: @user2141649 We can tell, that's why I gave you that link, lol. Enjoy and welcome to the fine world of insanity ... erm, I mean Programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EXAMPLE

### HTML

```
<div id="myBackground"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#myBackground {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;

    background: url(http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var imgUrl = "url(http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/themes/CSS-Tricks-10/images/bg.png)";

$(function() {    //    starts when page is loaded and ready
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myBackground").css("background-image", imgUrl);
    }, 2000);    //    2 second timer
})
```

---

## Alternate Style (with FadeIn/Out effect)

### HTML

```
<div id="myBackground">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png" />
    <img src="http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/themes/CSS-Tricks-10/images/bg.png" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#myBackground {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#myBackground img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#myBackground img:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function() {    //    starts when page is loaded and ready
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myBackground img:nth-child(1)").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#myBackground img:nth-child(2)").fadeIn(1500);
    }, 2000);    //    2 second timer
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>demo by roXon</title>


<script  src="s.js"></script>
<style>

article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, section { display: block; }

*{margin:0;padding:0;}
ul{list-style:none;}
a{text-decoration:none;}

body{background:#000;}

.images{
margin:50px;
position:relative;
}
.images img{
position:absolute;
}

.glowed{
box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 2px #fff
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<button id="stop">STOP IT!</button>

<div class="images">
<img src="images/9.jpg" />
<img src="images/9red.jpg" class="glowed"/>
</div>



<script>
var stop = false;

function loop(){
if(stop===false){
$('.images img:eq(1)').fadeIn(700, function(){
$(this).fadeOut(700,loop);
});
}
}

loop(); // start loop


$('#stop').click(function(){
stop=true;
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```