# How to get my background images to loop through

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to loop through background images every few seconds using jquery fadeIn
here is my HTML

```
<div class="bg" style="background: url(images/header1.jpg);"> </div>
<div class="bg" style="background: url(images/header2.jpg);"> </div>
<div class="bg" style="background: url(images/header3.jpg);"> </div>
```

and here is my Jquery

```
function changeBackground () {
    $(".bg").first().fadeIn("slow", function showNext() {
        $(this).next("div").delay(1000).fadeIn("slow", showNext);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 0);        
});
```

I'm not sure how to hide the previous image so I can reintroduce it next time. The function loops or maybe could be done using `z-index` to bring images to top?

Comment: i answered a question VERY MUCH like this several months ago, gimmie a few mins, i'm sure i can find it ...

Answer (score 5):

```
function changeBackground() {
    $(".bg").first().fadeIn("slow", function showNext() {
        var next = $(this).next('div').length ? $(this).next('div') : $(".bg").first();
        $(this).siblings().fadeOut('slow').delay(1000);
        next.fadeIn("slow", showNext);
    });
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 100);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/bQPUk/1/)

Comment: this works fantastic except i have a box absolutly positioned over the background "slideshow" which seems to also fade out with this code

Comment: @aztekgold well is it over or inside ?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I know this is a JQuery question, but I just wanted to give you another option. This type of effect can be achieved with just one div and some keyframes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  -webkit-animation: change-bg 10s ease infinite;
  animation: change-bg 10s ease infinite;

}

@-webkit-keyframes change-bg{
  0%  { background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500); }
  50% { background-image:  url(http://lorempixel.com/501/501);  }
  100% { background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/503/503); }
}

@keyframes change-bg {
  0%  { background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500); }
  50% { background-image:  url(http://lorempixel.com/501/501);  }
  100% { background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/503/503); }
}

/* add the other vendor prefixes if needed. */
```

Oh and also, if you wanted it to be a fullscreen background, you could use 0 divs. Just the keyframes and the rest of the css.

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: change-bg 10s ease infinite;
  animation: change-bg 10s ease infinite;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

@-webkit-keyframes change-bg{
  0%  { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/500/500'); }
  50% { background-image:  url('http://lorempixel.com/501/501');  }
  100% { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/503/503'); }
}

@keyframes change-bg {
  0%  { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/500/500'); }
  50% { background-image:  url('http://lorempixel.com/501/501');  }
  100% { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/503/503'); }
}

/* add the other vendor prefixes if needed. */
```

**[Fullscreen BG Demo](http://cdpn.io/tzsnm)**

**[Div Demo](http://jsbin.com/uyajaj/2)**

Comment: One issue tho, isn't `keyframes` CSS3 specific? Unfortunately, almost anything `CSS3` specific is useless in today's world unless you're making phone and tablet Apps specifically. Many PC's people use still use browsers that do not yet support CSS3 and HTML5 fully. Just a word of caution, not a criticism.

Comment: Yeah, keyframes are definitely not supported everywhere just yet, but we are on our way. According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes), keyframes are supported by 77.24% of current (in use) browsers.

Comment: never though of achieving it this way. i use keyframes in many sites which works for many browsers but make sure the main purpose of the page still works. for example it would not be suitable for a photographers portfolio. but for a added background effect with the page which maintains it functionality without the keyframes its perfect

Comment: well, i wouldn't trust just one site statistic. I can tell from one look at that site they are not account for military and medical traffic. Almost ALL military and medical within the US and many allies use IE, and those statics show very low IE usage.

Comment: Also noticed that site basis its statics on `statcounter` which is not very optimal, since this only covers people who `use` statcounter and not a broad range of browsers. Still keyframes will be nice in the future, I just simply suggest avoiding anything CSS3 or HTML5 specific until at least 2016, unless you're designing specifically for smaller devices like phones and tablets, likly to already have HTML5 and CSS3 browsers

Comment: Yeah, it may not be optimal right now...I'd personally probably use a JQuery solution still... but it's Friday and I wanted to css :) Still a decent solution IMO, so I'll leave it here.

Comment: @brbcoding I agree, and I give you props [+1], I just wanted to make sure you and future lookers might be aware of the issues that could arise trying to use such a CSS3 specific solution at such an early stage in transition of standards. We will be there before you know it tho!

Answer (score 2):

A fantastic plugin for background image slideshows is [Vegas](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/). It is extremely easy to set-up and use. I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but hopefully it will make coding easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found it! I answered a question Very similar to this one [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359492/changing-background-image-one-time-on-responsive-background-image/16359811#16359811)

Ok, the way i've done this is a little different from your layout. Though you could probably adjust it if you don't like my layout. I chose this layout because it seemed optimal.

I made a parent div that stretches for the background (also, you could set it to any size, place it anywhere, etc...). Next I put three `img` tags inside it with their respective links (replace links with your own).

Next comes a little CSS. You'll note I hide all images to start with and then set the first image to `display: block`, thus making it visible. The other key here is to set the images height and width to 100% so they stretch to parent.

Finally, just a little easy JS. Write it how you want it. In my example I simply grab currently visible, then look for what's next. If their are no images next, then I go back to the first one!

## jsFiddle Example




### jsFiddle [Modded using your jQuery style of code]




#### jsFiddle [Modded Example using your HTML Layout as well]

---

> Below is example code from my original layout and style

### HTML

```
<div id="myBackground">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png" />
    <img src="http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/themes/CSS-Tricks-10/images/bg.png" />
    <img src="http://cdn.buuteeq.com/upload/4074/header3.jpg.1140x481_default.jpg" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#myBackground {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#myBackground img {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    /* this will remove "white flash" between fade */
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#myBackground img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

### JS

```
function changeBackground() {
    //    here i select the current one visible,
    //    then i check if there is another omage after it, else i go back to the first
    var cur = $("#myBackground img:visible"),
        nxt = cur.next().length ? cur.next() : $("#myBackground img:first");
    cur.fadeOut("slow");
    nxt.fadeIn(1500);
}

$(function() {    //    starts when page is loaded and ready
    setInterval(changeBackground, 2250);    //    2 second timer
})
```

Comment: there is a flash of the white body background between transitions. i was looking to achieve a smooth transition

Comment: @aztekgold easy fix, just use `position: absolute;` on the images. I'll update answer and fiddles to show you...

Comment: @aztekgold fixed, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Visit  http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/show2.shtml It explains everything for a slideshow in javascript I used css and html5 my self. I go to http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/ for that.